# Uncaught TypeError: [Array].filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chart.js

I'm trying to pass data from a flask api to chart.js. We're using D3 to make the api call:

```
var queryUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/1/GenderOverTime";
var searchResults = [];

d3.json(queryUrl).then(function (chart_data) {
  searchResults = chart_data;});
  setTimeout(function(){init()},50)
```

Here is the section we're running into an error:

```
function init(){
  console.log("searchResults: ", searchResults);
  let selector = d3.select("#selDataset");
  let options = []
  filtered_data_for_chart = searchResults.filter(result=>{
      if (!options.includes(result.Sport)){
          options.push(result.Sport)
          selector
          .append("option")
          .text(result.Sport)
          .property("value", result.Sport);
      }
      
      return result.Sport==="Gymnastics"
  });
```

Upon running `init()`, we get "ChartJSfile.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: searchResults.filter is not a function".

Prior to using an api, we had another js script with the exact same data saved as an array object, and the chart & filter were working fine.

We added the `setTimeout` to allow some time to get the data, as the init() was running before data was loaded into the array.

sample of the data:

```
[{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61589a22cd5cc36ad5fc8898"
    },
    "Sport": "Aeronautics",
    "Year": 1936,
    "Sex": "M",
    "Name": 1,
    "Bronze": 0,
    "Silver": 0,
    "Gold": 1,
    "No Win": 0,
    "Attempts": 1,
    "Wins": 1
  },... ]
```

Comment: What does your data looks like ?

Comment: just added a sample. We've confirmed the original js script and the api output are the same. The only difference being the original source js had "let searchResults = [...]

Comment: Before `searchResults.filter()` you are doing `console.log("searchResults: ", searchResults);` Do you see any data in the console?

Comment: Yep!
searchResults:  [{'_id': ObjectId('615ddee73f5fdcc7c7436939'), 'Sport': 'Aeronautics', 'Year': 1936, 'Sex': 'M', 'Name': 1, 'Bronze': 0, 'Silver': 0, 'Gold': 1, 'No Win': 0, 'Attempts': 1, 'Wins': 1},...]

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: I have. no error, but the output is a blank list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work properly [as you can see here](https://codepen.io/trouba/pen/BaZXxKb)

You might want to refactor it to be sure to have access to the data in search results when you need it:

```
var queryUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/1/GenderOverTime";
var searchResults = [];

d3.json(queryUrl).then(function (chart_data) {
  searchResults = chart_data;
  init(searchResults);
});


function init(results) {
  console.log("searchResults: ", results);
  let selector = d3.select("#selDataset");
  let options = [];
  filtered_data_for_chart = results.filter((result) => {
    if (!options.includes(result.Sport)) {
      options.push(result.Sport);
      selector
        .append("option")
        .text(result.Sport)
        .property("value", result.Sport);
    }

    return result.Sport === "Gymnastics";
  });
}
```

Comment: It must be something with the API response. When we reference a js file with the array copy/pasted, it works fine.

Comment: Realized the issue was with my flask app. I was pushing the chart data from Mongo DB within an f-string, so chart.js wouldn't interpret the data as a string. Redid the API route query to also not include Mongo's default "_id:" column and everything loaded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.from()` to create a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an array-like or iterable object. So this should solve your issue:

```
const searchResultsList = Array.from(searchResults)
filtered_data_for_chart = searchResultsList.filter(result=>{...})
```

Comment: the TypeError is gone, but this console log at the bottom outputs a blank list:

`function init(){`

`console.log("searchResults: ", searchResults);`
`let selector = d3.select("#selDataset");`
`let options = []`
`const searchResultsList = Array.from(searchResults)`
`filtered_data_for_chart = searchResultsList.filter(result=>{`
...
`console.log(default_filtered)`